# py2neo: batch create indexed node with multiple key:value pairs

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

With

```
batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
for n in nodes:
    batch.create_indexed_node_or_fail(index, key, value, {node properties})
batch.submit()
```

you can easily create indexed nodes in a batch.

But how can I create a node in a batch and add multiple key:value pairs at the same time? Or add the node to multiple indices?

One idea I thought of is to first create the nodes and then add them to the indices in a second batch:

```
for n in nodes:
    batch.create({node properties})
results = batch.submit()

for r in results:
    batch add node to index1
    batch add node to index2
batch.submit()
```

But this seems to complicated. Py2neo is so amazing, there must be an easier way.

---

Based on Nigel's answer, I tried to this for a list of nodes:

```
batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
item_in_batch = 0

for n in list_of_nodes:
    batch.create(n) # this works, all nodes are created
    batch.add_indexed_node("people", "key", "value from n", item_in_batch)
    batch.add_indexed_node("people", "key2", "other value from n", item_in_batch)
    i += 1
batch.submit()
```

Some nodes end up in my index, but not all. When I search the index for ('key:value-from-n") it returns a node but not the correct one. How can I access the 'internal' ID of the nodes when I try to add them to an index?

---

I tried the (currently testing) version 1.6.0 of py2neo and it works!

```
n = batch.create(node)
```

now returns a request object which can be used within the batch to refer to the node.

An example is in the [docs for 1.6.0](http://book.py2neo.org/en/release-1.6.0/batches/#py2neo.neo4j.WriteBatch.create)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need two batches. You should be able to create and add in the same batch. Something like:

```
batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph_db)
batch.create({"name": "Alice})
batch.add_indexed_node("people", "name", "Alice", 0)
batch.add_indexed_node("employees", "id", 2345678, 0)
batch.add_indexed_node("fighter_pilots", "call_sign", "Silver Eagle", 0)
batch.submit()
```

For unique indexing, you could use `add_indexed_node_or_fail` instead.

And thanks for the compliment :-)

Comment: Thanks Nigel! I'll try that. I kind of don't get why I can reference the last node with '0'. It will have another id in neo4j, right? Would this also work if batch.create() and batch.add_indexed_node() are in a loop and submitted after creating a couple hundred nodes? I think I need to have a look at your code try to understand this better :)

Comment: The zero doesn't refer to the node ID as created by the server, it refers to the zeroth item in that batch, in this case the newly created node.

Comment: This works for single nodes, but not if I create more in my batch. I think it doesn't refer to the correct item in the batch when I iterate. I edited my question with the code, any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: I tried version 1.6.0 and it works! Question is edited ... sorry for spamming :)

Comment: That makes me happy :-)